# How to handle Angular 2+ code updates?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to handle when an Angular 2+ app is updated?

Note: NOT WHEN ANGULAR IS UPDATED for example from 4.1.0 to 4.1.2 (this not)

when i say "updated" i mean to:

**When code has changed** and is published to production.

when i publish an update to the system built in Angular 4, the view of clients just start to have errors because javascript of NG has changed, even have other javascript generated names.

- what's the right way to handle this?
- Angular has "something" official for say to the Browser when to update code/resources?

or something like that.

thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the problem is, e.g. what *javascript of NG has changed, even have other javascript generated names* means. If the problem is that JS scripts are cached on browser side and not updated automatically, this has nothing to do with Angular. This is about cache invalidation which is specific to server side. If you're using Angular CLI (the question says nothing on that), there may be solutions that embrace it.

Comment: the problem is when an app built in Angular is published the client visit our site "example.com" and gets current version of that View of Angular, but when you fix something like a bug, you re-publish a change. but clients have to refresh to see that change. most of clients don't know when a change has been published. how Angular can handle automatically this.

Comment: It can't. It could be random JS script, and the result would be same. Again, this is specific to your server side. Not Angular. Updated script files should have different filenames (containing a version or a hash), or different urls (`?` query with a version or a hash). Cache invalidation was discussed on SO a lot of times. Consider re-asking the question with precise details on your server side if you won't solve it from existing answers.

Comment: I don't think @NinjaCoding is referring to cache invalidation, but notifying a user via the app, that the app has changed.

Comment: you can't really tell the browser when to update without a web socket connection or if logic is already built into the client and on your server to check for code updates.  Generally though, wihtout API updates, I don't see how old code could suddenly break because a new version exists in the world.

Comment: and if you version your APIs, not even an API update should break the app...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an "official" way to force a client side reload when you deploy new code. Usually this should not be a problem, because when the client calls the app, it caches the JS and CSS files, so a deploy should not have any effects on the version of the application a client is currently running...

But if this really is a problem, you could provide your application version via an HTTP API, have your angular app check it on every interaction, and reload the page if the version has changed.

**version.txt**

```
1.0.1
```

**src/environments/environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    version: '1.0.2'
};
```

**src/app/version.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class VersionService {
    constructor(private __httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    checkVersion() {
        this.__httpClient.get('/version.txt').subscribe(data => {
            if (data != environment.version) {
                alert('Code is outdated, website will reload');
                window.reload();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a constructor to all your components and check the version

**src/app/app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private __versionService: VersionService) {
    this.__versionService.checkVersion();
}
```

Note: this code is completely untested :-) You might have to tinker with it... Also, I am not sure if this actually IS the best way to do it, but I couldn't find a better answer anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you so much @masterfloda!!**

I been working in your aproach, and it worked like a charm, I did some tunning to your code so I hope you don't mind if I publish the updated code to help other people facing the same problem.

**version.txt**

```
1.0
```

> I noticed that when it was more than one point betwen numbers (0.0.0 -> 0.0) it fails comparing the values.

I didn't use the src/environments/environment.prod.ts aproach because I wanted a way to update the value of version inside src/environments/environment.prod.ts and was not sure how to do it once in production, so I stored the value in local storage.

**src/app/version.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Compiler } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalVariablesService } from '../services/global.service';

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440576/how-to-handle-angular-2-code-updates
@Injectable()
export class VersionService {
    constructor(private __httpClient: HttpClient,
      private _compiler: Compiler,
      public variablesService: GlobalVariablesService
    ) { }

    checkVersion() {
        this.__httpClient.get('https://host.com/version.txt?'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10000),{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
          response => {

            let text_version  = response;
            let stored_version = this.variablesService.getVersion();
            //alert('text_version: '+text_version);

            if(stored_version == undefined){
              this.variablesService.setVersion(text_version);
            } else if (+text_version != +stored_version) {
                this.reloadAndStore(text_version);
           }
        },
        error => {
         console.log(<any>error);
          }
        );
      }

      reloadAndStore(text_version){
        //alert('Code is outdated, website will reload');
        this._compiler.clearCache();
        this.variablesService.setVersion(text_version);
        location.reload();

      }

    }
```

> version.txt?'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10000)

Here you will see I'm using a random param, because if not I noticed when the web app is installed in ios homescreen it catches even that version.text file.

**../services/global.service**

```
...
      getVersion() {
        if(this.deCodeLocal('storedVersion') === null){
          return undefined;
        } else {
          return this.deCodeLocal('storedVersion');
        }
      }



      setVersion(val) {
        this.enCodeLocal('storedVersion', val);
      }
...
```

**src/app/app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private __versionService: VersionService) {
    this.__versionService.checkVersion();
}
```

I hope it helps somebody, thank so much.